# DisplayNameAttribute for anonymous class

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

If I had a non-anonymous class like this, I know I can use `DisplayNameAttribute` like this.

```
class Record{

    [DisplayName("The Foo")]
    public string Foo {get; set;}

    [DisplayName("The Bar")]
    public string Bar {get; set;}

}
```

but I have

```
var records = (from item in someCollection
               select{
                   Foo = item.SomeField,
                   Bar = item.SomeOtherField,
               }).ToList();
```

and I use `records` for `DataSource` for a DataGrid. The column headers show up as `Foo` and `Bar` but they have to be `The Foo` and `The Bar`. I cannot create a concrete class for a few different internal reasons and it will have to be an anonymous class. Given this, is there anyway I can set `DisplayNameAttrubute` for members of this anonymous class?

I tried

```
[DisplayName("The Foo")] Foo = item.SomeField
```

but it won't compile.

Thanks.

Comment: I avoided anonymous classes for this reason, and just made a light weight data object.  In your case it'd be the Record class you already posted.  Is there a technical need to use an anonymous class here?

Comment: "I cannot create a concrete class for a few different internal reasons" There's no reason ever not to be able to create a new class. you running out of disk space or something?

Comment: This isn't meant to be rude, but if there was someone internal at my organization saying that I cannot create a class I'd start polishing my resume.

Comment: Well, one of the primary reasons is that I have about 70 queries like this and I did not want to create a class for each query just to use the `DisplayNameAttribute`. The other reason was that there were plans to use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) to be able to let the user choose columns during runtime.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy sounds like you might need to normalize your database a bit. Even if you could choose which colomns are returned, the DAO could have everything on it and whatever wasn't selected would be null. I'm more curious about a scenario where it makes sense for a user to choose the columns that are selected.

Comment: @vcsjones An example scenario would be Windows Explorer. it displays the crucial columns by default (Details View) but the user has options to include other columns like "Authors", "Date Created", etc

Comment: @TheOtherGuy Yes, but that doesn't mean Windows Explorer "forgets" all of the other information the file has. Just select it all anyway and only display what the user has selected. There is little advantage to actually dynamically changing the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following solution:

```
dataGrid.SetValue(
    DataGridUtilities.ColumnHeadersProperty,
    new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "Foo", "The Foo" },
        { "Bar", "The Bar" },
    });

dataGrid.ItemsSource = (from item in someCollection
           select{
               Foo = item.SomeField,
               Bar = item.SomeOtherField,
           }).ToList();
```

Then you have the following Attached Property code:

```
public static class DataGridUtilities
{
    public static IDictionary<string,string> GetColumnHeaders(
        DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IDictionary<string,string>)obj.GetValue(ColumnHeadersProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumnHeaders(DependencyObject obj,
        IDictionary<string, string> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnHeadersProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnHeadersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ColumnHeaders",
            typeof(IDictionary<string, string>),
            typeof(DataGrid),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, ColumnHeadersPropertyChanged));

    static void ColumnHeadersPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null && e.NewValue != null)
        {
            dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += AddColumnHeaders;
        }
    }

    static void AddColumnHeaders(object sender,
        DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var headers = GetColumnHeaders(sender as DataGrid);
        if (headers != null && headers.ContainsKey(e.PropertyName))
        {
            e.Column.Header = headers[e.PropertyName];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 That might be a good way to tackle this problem. I'll try it out and post feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot apply an attribute to an anonymous type. The compiler simply doesn't support it. You could go really off the wagon and use something like Mono.Cecil as a post-build step to put the attribute there, but that's hardly something you want to consider. Why does it have to be anonymous?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have included the main reasons as to why I would prefer anonymous class in the question comments section.